# White smoke from exhaust and loss of power

Tags: smoke, vauxhall, power-loss, zafira

I have a Vauxhall Zafira and I am losing power, and have white smoke coming out of the back of it. I have had a new reconditioned engine put in literally 2 days ago to fix this issue as they thought it was the only option at the garage but the issue persists. I really cannot afford this as I am a minicab driver and I’m already out of pocket and consequently not earning. Does anyone have any idea what it could be? The garage have also said my coolant hasn’t decreased. Cheers for any advice.

Comment: If they have replaced the engine and you still have smoke coming out then they've either put in another bad engine or they've ripped you off.

Comment: What does the exhaust smell like? Does it have a sweet smell to it or is it oily? Is the engine turbocharged? Can you give us the specifications of the engine (ie: diesel or petrol; 3 or 4 cylinder; etc).

Comment: Did they give you any rationale for replacing the engine?  That's a MAJOR repair and goes way beyond the all-to-common "throw parts at a problem until it's resolved" mentality.